# Replace Text in a Div with text in another Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="replaceMe">I'm a Girl</div>

<div id="iamReplacement" style="display:none">No your are a Boy Girl</div>
```

the text in `replaceMe` should be replaced with the text in `iamReplacement`

i think it can be done in java script or jquery.. can some one help me on this..

**Tried** (not working)

```
<script>
    jQuery('#replaceMe').replaceWith(jQuery('#iamReplacement'));
</script>
```

Comment: use `innerHTML` and assignment operator `=` for this

Comment: Keep in mind, you are replacing a `div` with an INVISIBLE `div`

Comment: Your sample fails as it does a complete replace - the #replaceMe div is removed, and then you put the exact HTML of the #iamReplacement div in it's place.  Use a web developer tool, and you'll see this happening in the DOM.  You likely want to use .text() instead of .replaceWith().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for jQuery:

```
$("#replaceMe").html($("#iamReplacement").html());
```

Or pure JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("replaceMe").innerHTML = document.getElementById("iamReplacement").innerHTML;
```

Comment: @BlackCoder No problems :) Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$('#replaceMe').html($('#iamReplacement').html());
```

Comment: sorry rob! matt already answered a min before you :( have to select his answer

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#replaceMe').html(
        jQuery('#iamReplacement').html()
    );
});
```

EDIT: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dbawq/)

Comment: zigdawgydawg, thanks for taking time :( but matt already answered this questions. ones again THANKS :-)  `+1 for you`

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing your `div` with an ***invisible*** `div`. If you are going to use `.replaceWith()`, make sure to also use [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) since it is replacing the original `div` with the invisible one:

```
jQuery('#replaceMe').replaceWith(jQuery('#iamReplacement').show());
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/dyZ3A/

Comment: Dom, thanks for taking time :( but matt already answered this questions. ones again THANKS :-) `+1 for you`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("replaceMe").innerHTML = document.getElementById("iamReplacement").innerHTML;
```

Check it out in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vwWhr/

Comment: @smeets thanks for taking time :( but matt already answered this questions. ones again THANKS :-) `+1 for you`

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$('#replaceMe').html($('#iamReplacement').html());
</script>
```

Comment: Manu, thanks for taking time :( but matt already answered this questions. ones again THANKS :-) `+1 for you`

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 //you can put your code code in your event
  $('#replaceMe').html($('#iamReplacement').html());

});
```

Comment: @EshanSahu thanks for taking time :( but matt already answered this questions. ones again THANKS :-)